# In TFS how do I pull all the items that were assigned to me between certain dates in the past?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to figure out the way to pull all the items that were on my plate between certain dates. Is this possible? Could you please help me to figure out how to write a query for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

The best that I know how to do is to set `'Assigned To' Was Ever @Me`, then manually scan the list of work items returned (setting other fields as necessary to filter the results). In the UI, at least, there isn't a way to query on historical data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via query window as well, below is my query that i use to see what have i been working on in the past two sprints.

[image: Searching for past work items through query window]

This will give you any tickets you worked on regardless of who they are currently assigned to (system test / uat or whatever).

You can add more clauses and have Changed Date > xxx AND ChangedDate < xxx to find what you are looking for in any given dates.