# How to identify Azure DevOps workitems that were assigned to me in the past 4 days?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

There are lots of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382303/in-tfs-how-do-i-pull-all-the-items-that-were-assigned-to-me-between-certain-date) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621176/find-workitems-that-were-assigned-and-finished-in-the-last-30-days) from a long time ago, but I don't see an answer.

I have the following setup, which does return all work items that were assigned to me and where `Changed Date` was changed in the last 4 days.
[image]

The problem is that if someone goes into the ticket and changes something, the `Changed Date` is updated and the item ends up back on my list.

So how do I limit the results to include work items that were assigned to me within the last 4 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a field that contains the data about Chaged Date of Assigned to, so you can't query work items assigned to you recently.

In addition to the workaround in the link you provided, if you are using an [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops), you can also use custom fields as a workaround.

Here are the detailed steps:

1. Go to Organization Settings -> Boards/Process. Select your inherited process. Select a work item type that you want to query. Click on "New field" and fill in the form. The Type of this field should be "**Date**" .Then, click "Add field".

   [image: Create a field]
2. Select "Rules" tab. Click "New rule" with following configuration:

   Conditions: When **A change was made to the value of ...** | **Assigned To**

   Actions: Then **Use the current time to set the value of ..** | Select the field created in #1.

   [image: Create a rule]

After that you can query workitems that were assigned to you in the past 4 days using the new field.